# Login con Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, login, maven, spring-security

Hola Estoy aprendiendo a configurar el login con Spring boot y maven. Sigo un tutorial pero resulta que en la configuración de seguridad tengo un método que está obsoleto y no se como reemplazarlo ni con qué. El método obsoleto es "authorizeRequests"

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda ya que estoy muy perdido.

Comment: el primer paso es que averigües que versión usas para saber que tan obsoleto es tu código, si no sabes como te recomiendo hacer otra pregunta específicamente para eso

Comment: En caso de que estes en al ultima version de spring, [este fue reemplazado por](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html) `authorizeHttpRequests()`

Comment: Gracias a los que me respondieron. Gracias a ello opté por la salida más fácil. Pasar mi proyecto a una versión más vieja de spring boot y así seguir el tutorial. La verdad es que entre que soy autodidacta y muy novato se me complican las cosas.